# pgn-extract suppress output

Tags: pgn, fen

I installed `pgn-extract_17.38` and want to suppress the output of

```
$ FEN=$(echo "1.d4 Nf6 2.Nf3 e6 3. *" | pgn-extract -F)
Processing stdin

1 game matched out of 1.
```

I read about suppressing methods on the [website](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/help.html#skipmatching). But till now it does not work for me. Has any one experience in that tool?

Comment: The author of the software recently joined this site, he will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the --quiet option that should do it:

FEN=$(echo "1.d4 Nf6 2.Nf3 e6 3. *" | pgn-extract -F --quiet)

kentdjb (author of pgn-extract)